# Am getting un-expected NULL values in a Datagridview's calculated column

Tags: winforms, datagridview, dataset, calculated-columns

I have a Bindingsource that am setting as a datasource to a DataGridView control. In its dataset query i have a calculated column(Column1). When i go to the Bindingsource's tasks and click **Preview Data** i can, for my **Column1** other rows have data values returned and for other rows NULL is returned which is ok and expected.

The problem is that when i set this same bindingSource as a datasource to a Datagridview control, all the expected rows are returned but for all the rows, **Column1** is NULL yet like i said, when i go the BindingSource Tasks and click Preview Data, i can see that **not all rows have NULL** for column1.

some thing strange is happening to the data during the process of binding the results to the Datagridview control and am abit confused? Any Ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Have looked your Column1' Sort Expression? Second Look the Columns's type.  If it's TemplateBound you must arrange bind on itemdatabound event

Comment: Current SortMode = Automatic and Columns's type = DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

Comment: Could you put a breakpoint and look for expecting data column? If datacolumn comes blank, yep there is a trouble with dataflow...